# RedissonLocalCachedMap.clear() has a small delay

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I noticed that when my code calls `RedissonLocalCachedMap.clear()` and then immediately reads from it, it doesn't always get a cleared cache. It appears that there is a small delay between calling `clear()` and the cache actually getting cleared. Is that correct? If so, is there a sync method I can call that doesn't return until it gets cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause. It was due to a bug in older version of redission.
It was fixed in redission v3.16.5 with this comment:

```
Fixed - RLocalCachedMap.delete() method clears local cache asynchronously
```

Fixed code:

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/commit/42f27d89bc5096fce7fb4483121b0d5f5d49123f